# Stripe Widget converts balance to thousands on declined card

Tags: stripe-payments

We have integrated the Stripe widget into our checkout, works great! UNTIL a customers card is declined then the total for some reason converts into thousands

E.g if a customers is paying for goods worth £520 and the card is declined the balance is converted to £52,000.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's amount parameters are in pence for British Pounds, and cents for US Dollars. You're likely doing some conversions wrong on your own end.

Also, you have provided 0 code, so this question kinda violates the SO rules. You should add more information and code snippets of what you've already tried or this question may be at risk of being closed.